# Can I bin jQuery UI sortable on document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've a bit of a problem. I have a sortable within a div. This div get's reloaded with AJAX some time. When it get's reloaded, it don't works anymore. I know this problem and tried doing this here:

```
$(document).on("sortable",  "#element" function () {
    ...
});
```

But this don't works no more also after reloading the page. So is there any way to keep the sortable during an AJAX reload?

Comment: You have given too little information to be able to understand your problem. Do you mean bind? `bin` means throw out. What is `on.("sortable"... ` supposed to do?

Comment: This is a jQuery UI lib as written in the title and the problem is that a local binding don't works anymore when the element get's reloaded via AJAX where the binding was bind to.

Comment: You have to refresh the sortable

Comment: And how can I do this? Should I add it again after the reload?

Comment: Search google or SO for sortable refresh after ajax